# Create a Tradingview Alert with a delay

Tags: pine-script

I want to create an alert with a certain delay after receiving the condition.

The indicator repaints a lot. I don't want to wait for the bar close. So I want to create a system, where the script checks after a defined time (1-2sec) to see if the condition for triggering the alert is still there and creates the alert accordingly.

How should I tackle with time in TV?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`varip`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_varip) to time the duration of conditions in the realtime bar.

[This](https://www.tradingview.com/script/ppQxBISk-Using-varip-variables-PineCoders/) shows a few use cases, including yours:

```
f_secondsSince(_cond, _resetCond) =>
    // bool _cond     : condition to test.
    // bool _resetCond: when `true`, the duration resets.
    varip float _timeBegin = na
    varip bool  _lastCond  = false
    if _resetCond
        // Reset time if required.
        _timeBegin := _cond ? timenow : na
    else if _cond
        if not _lastCond
            // First occurrence of true `_cond`; save beginnning time.
            _timeBegin := timenow
    else
        // Condition is not true; reset beginning time.
        _timeBegin := na
    // Remember the last state of the `_cond` so we can detect transitions.
    _lastCond := _cond
    // Return seconds since beginning of condition, or `na`.
    float _return = (timenow - _timeBegin) / 1000
```